# Complete Graphs

Tags: graph-theory

If I have a complete graph with 18 vertices, and I take a 4-clique (with all the edges and vertices colored red) and 3-clique (with all the edges and vertices colored blue), will these cliques have edges connecting them? I say yes because they both come from a complete graph and therefore the cliques should have edges connecting them.

Does anyone else agree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is correct.  In a complete graph, any two distinct vertices have an edge connecting them, so in particular if you take a vertex from the 4-clique and a different vertex from the 3-clique, there is an edge between them.

Comment: Thank you. For some reason, my research prof said this wasn't true so I am guessing that he and I were thinking of two different things when we were speaking.